# Dynamically resize side-by-side images with different dimensions to the same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have two images side-by-side within a block-level container with arbitrarily different dimensions (as in, they could be any two images) that I want to dynamically adjust the width of so that the overall height of the two images is the same. I don't *think* this can be done in CSS from everything I've seen (although possibly with the flexbox model, but I don't know enough about it to say) so I may need a JavaScript solution, but the ones I came up with failed due to either not knowing the overall height of the bounding box, or the fact that adjusting the height of the images affected the height of the bounding box which meant it was constantly re-adjusting itself.

This is an example of arbitrary image heights: https://jsfiddle.net/c6h466xf/

And this is what I'm trying to achieve (although obviously without hard-coding the widths, I want those to be resolved dynamically): https://jsfiddle.net/c6h466xf/4/

This is what I'm starting with (links to JSFiddle need code):

**CSS**

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
}

 div.container img {
    width: 49%;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/g0XwGQp.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sFNj4bs.jpg">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I don't want to set a static height on the container element, because that stops it from responding to the width of the overall page, so that the images resize dynamically to each other *and* responsively to the width of the page, so their total combined width is always (for example) 80% of the page width whatever the viewing device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's responsive, use percentage heights and widths:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.container img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/g0XwGQp.jpg" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sFNj4bs.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like what I need. Does this still work if I have many other styles of container elements on a very long page (specifically, other types of images, like single panoramic images spanning the entire width, single images spanning 80% of the width and centered etc.) and won't mess up the browser's calculations of what the height actually is?

Comment: @WheresWardy As long as the images are bigger than the height of `.container`, they should be fine. If you want to literally force it to be max height, just remove the `max-` from the img css. Percentages are calculated based on the height and/or width of the immediate parent.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it by height. Give your container `div` a fixed height.

Here is a solution for you:

```
div.container {
    height:200px;
}

div.container img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c6h466xf/5/)

You have 2 other options to get all your images to the same height:

You can place an `overflow:hidden` on the container `div`

Or

Clip your images to the same size: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for your images:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/g0XwGQp.jpg" class="example" >
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/sFNj4bs.jpg" class="example" >
```

Then you need to set the height of your container:

```
div.container {
    height:200px;
}
```

In your JavaScript:

```
var yourImg = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
if(yourImg && yourImg.style) {
    yourImg.style.height = '100%';
    yourImg.style.float = 'left';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple code, check the following:

**HTML code:**

```
<table class="Table">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/1.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/2.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/3.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/4.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table { width: 100%; }
table img {
   max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding-left: 5px; border: none;
}
```